# Doctrine - Nested Entity subdirectory/namespaces

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've searched around quite a bit for an answer to this and I'm just not getting anything that's sounding reasonable right now.  So, here is the dilemma...

I have an `Entity` directory with a nesting structure.  This just works far better for our organization.  So, we might have something like:

```
./Entity
./Entity/User
./Entity/User.php
./Entity/User/Type
./Entity/User/Type/Administrator.php
./Entity/User/Type/Editor.php
```

So, basically 2 types of users.  In this case, the namespace would follow PSR4.  In the case above, we'd have the following files:

*User.php*

```php
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_key", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "administrator" = "Entity\User\Type\Administrator",
 *      "editor" = "Entity\User\Type\Editor",
 * })
 *
 * @ORM\Table
 */
abstract class User
```

*Administrator.php*

```php
namespace Entity\User\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Entity\User;

/**
 * Administrator Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Administrator extends User
```

And with this, I'm getting the following error:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Entity class 'Entity\User\Type\Administrator' used in the discriminator map of class 'Entity\User' does not exist.

/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:479
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:2875
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:2847
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:265
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:79
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:155
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:306
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:82
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:185
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:288
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1764
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1737
/srv/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:610
```

So, how do I register this namespace, or what's the exact issue here?  I've tried explicitly passing the entity path to the `AnnotationDriver`, which is being used for mapping.

I'm not looking for Symfony yml config solution here.  I'm also not looking for 2 instances of the entity manager.  I want one entity manager and I want these namespaces supported.

When generating the proxy classes, I've confirmed that they properly recognize the nested namespace entities and generate the proxy classes properly.

**UPDATE:**

It seems clear that the proxy classes are generated with the additional namespace, as the actual entities are structured.  So, I guess that looks correct.

```php
// Normal
namespace Entity\Proxy\__CG__\Entity;
// Nested
namespace Entity\Proxy\__CG__\Entity\User\Type;
```

However, these proxy class files sit at the same level as all of the other proxy classes - no nesting.

I don't know enough about how proxies are loaded and used within the caching later to determine if this is an issue or not.  A couple tests by changing the namespace and nested in dirs within the proxy path didn't have any positive results, possibly because it was still breaking the logic, or because this is a non-issue based on the way proxy loading works.

Comment: You say you don't want a Symfony based solution but the ORM prefix comes from Symfony.  When using out of the box Doctrine you would normally just use @Entity instead of @ORM\Entity.  But I suspect you have a simple PSR4 namespace mapping issue.  Using Entity as a root namespace prefix is a bit strange.  Usually you would have a project wide namespace prefix which in turn becomes part of your PSR4 mapping.  I test your code using a plain doctrine bootstrap file and it worked as expected.  I can post my code as an answer if you want.

Comment: If not then show your bootstrap.php code and the psr4 section of composer.json.  Remember to run 'composer dump-autoload' after making any psr4 changes to composer.json.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the input.  The namespace is just for example purposes here, it's all pseudo-code.  Are you suggesting that, what's described in this issue, is possible and supported by Doctrine?  The `ORM` use alias, just allows for less use statements.  There is nothing inherently "Symfony" about that.

There are not any autoloading issues with Composer.  There are services located in similar nested directories working well there and with Symonfy's DI component.

Unfortunately, the bootstrapping for the entity manager is rather large and complex.  But, if this is supposed to work...

Comment: Issue is resolved.  The filename had a leading (space) prepended.  *sigh*

Comment: Glad you got it working.  It has always been a bit confusing (to me) that the examples in the Doctrine docs seldom use ORM while the Symfony ones do.  And if you take one of the Doctrine examples and add the use statement it still does not work.  You need to use a particular annotation reader.  Just one of those things.